# wireshark: decrypt live SSL traffic

Tags: ssl, wireshark

w.r.t decryting SSL traffic with wireshark, I've seen the sample capture from wireshark website and it worked fine. What I'd like to achieve is to decode live traffic. So the key I guess is to identify private key file on the system. I'm using Xubuntu 13.10 64 bit. Looking around, I discovered a file /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key. So I setup wireshark to use this key. But it didn't work and wireshark complained about it.

I'm quite sure this is something that can be achieved. So what's the piece I'm missing?

Comment: Is the server running SSL the same one as your Xubuntu machine?  If not, you need the server's key, not yours.

Comment: @Paul why the server's key? The traffic is decrypted locally anyway right?

Comment: The server encrypts the data with its private key, wireshark uses the private key to decrypt the session, to capture the session key.  Any private keys on the client are not involved in the SSL session, unless the client and server happen to be the same machine.

Comment: @Paul, isn't the data from server to client encrypted with client's public key? If it's encrypted with server's private key, how can the client decrypt it?

Comment: This is the fundamentals of SSL - asymmetric encryption.  The content is encrypted with the server key and decrypted with the server certificate.  The cert is provided to you when you connect.  This is only used to establish a symmetric key which is then used to encrypt the bulk of the session.  Wireshark needs to get the session key that the client produces and encrypts with the public key (the certificate) and sends to the server, so it needs the server private key to decrypt the session key.